# how to derisk amazon affiliate business (physical product delivery in hundreds of niches)?

Tags: options, risk

We have a small business where we publish content online and make revenue from amazon commissions. Someone buys something using our affiliate links, then amazon pays us commission of 1-5%.
It generates between 10-15k a month in revenue. We link to tens of thousands of products in every possible category. Electronics, household, music, gaming, sports, tools, health, pets, DIY, etc.
The location is US and Europe. We're already down in revenue because of quarantines. Amazon affiliate commissions is our only source of revenue.

Now my question is how can we derisk this business right now if amazon restricts the sale of physical products during the quarantines? Our revenues my drop 80-90% over night.

I thought about shorting Amazon, but I think maybe AWS would do well during the quarantines. Also maybe QE could keep amazon afloat. The amazon stock doesn't seem 100% correlated to our business. Then I thought about maybe shorting Fedex or DHL or some delivery service, but then again I don't know much about these companies and how they would be impacted.

Comment: If income dries up you're better off preserving your cash than gambling it. At this point stocks have been hit hard, some think they will slide much further, some don't, nobody knows with any certainty.

Comment: I don't think you can, it sounds like you are at amazons mercy and they can decide to screw you over at any time, regardless of their own successes or failures.

Comment: You probably should model your risk as a combination of two risks. People may postpone certain purchases, and people may forego other purchases altogether. Restaurants are really hard-hit, because that lose sales when they're closed. Cars on the other hand get old and need to be replaced eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could short Amazon's stock, either through a short sell or a put option, but both involve taking a new risk. I'm not sure that this additional risk offsets your existing risks that well.

Perhaps a better approach would be to diversify your risks, by finding an additional revenue stream.